# Babel vs. a webpack loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, transpiler

I have limited experience with both, however, I had a basic question based on my understanding of what they do. A webpack loader seems to be converting source from one form to another. Babel, on the other hand (is a transpiler) that converts your new JavaScript code into old JavaScript code (that runs on all browsers).

Both seem to do a very similar thing. Why can't we just use a webpack loader that "converts new JavaScript code into old JavaScript code" instead of using Babel in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right in your understanding, except for the use case of a loader and a transpiler. A loader is a generic term in the Webpack ecosystem while a transpiler is an example of a loader (e.g. [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) is a loader whose duty is to transpile your JavaScript code).

> Why can't we just use a Webpack loader that "converts new JavaScript code into old JavaScript code " instead of using Babel in the pipeline?
>
> Because there's no loader that transpiles your JavaScript code that comes with Webpack. Here's a [list of loaders](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/awesome-webpack#loaders). The Webpack team maintains some of them.

Comment: @nev.m I hope this answers your question. An upvote is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Babel is not specific to webpack.
A webpack loader is often just a wrapper for a transpiler. Webpack needs a loader to plumb input to, and output from a transpiler, like `babel-loader` does for Babel.
Webpack needs loaders because there is no standard API for transpilers: some have a JavaScript API, some use stdin/stdout, some write to files...